# SoundPool puse works only one time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, soundpool

This is my code:

```
    int SC5;
    sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    SC5  = sp.load(this, R.raw.c5, 1);

    C5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // PRESSED
                    sp.play(SC5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    return true; 


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // RELEASED
                    sp.pause(SC5);

                    return true; 
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I want when I released button my soundpool stop playing, this code works, but only one time. When i press button for second time, I can't stop sound
and I couldn't use `autoPause();`  because I have other files in this soundpool

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

```
int streamId = -1;
C5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                streamId = sp.play(SC5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                return true; 


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // RELEASED
                sp.pause(streamId);

                return true; 
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

You cannot use SC5 to pause the sound since SC5 turns out to be a soundId.

For more information, you should check the document of SoundPool, and **PAY ATTENTION to the ID you use to play (soundId) or pause (streamId) a sound**.

```
 /**
 * Play a sound from a sound ID.
 *
 * Play the sound specified by the soundID. This is the value 
 * returned by the load() function. Returns a non-zero streamID
 * if successful, zero if it fails. The streamID can be used to
 * further control playback. Note that calling play() may cause
 * another sound to stop playing if the maximum number of active
 * streams is exceeded. A loop value of -1 means loop forever,
 * a value of 0 means don't loop, other values indicate the
 * number of repeats, e.g. a value of 1 plays the audio twice.
 * The playback rate allows the application to vary the playback
 * rate (pitch) of the sound. A value of 1.0 means play back at
 * the original frequency. A value of 2.0 means play back twice
 * as fast, and a value of 0.5 means playback at half speed.
 *
 * @param soundID a soundID returned by the load() function
 * @param leftVolume left volume value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
 * @param rightVolume right volume value (range = 0.0 to 1.0)
 * @param priority stream priority (0 = lowest priority)
 * @param loop loop mode (0 = no loop, -1 = loop forever)
 * @param rate playback rate (1.0 = normal playback, range 0.5 to 2.0)
 * @return non-zero streamID if successful, zero if failed
 */
public final int play(int soundID, float leftVolume, float rightVolume,
        int priority, int loop, float rate);

/**
 * Pause a playback stream.
 *
 * Pause the stream specified by the streamID. This is the
 * value returned by the play() function. If the stream is
 * playing, it will be paused. If the stream is not playing
 * (e.g. is stopped or was previously paused), calling this
 * function will have no effect.
 *
 * @param streamID a streamID returned by the play() function
 */
public final void pause(int streamID);
```

Comment: sorry , i edit my post . now you could see better . my only problem is my pause just work one time , when i play again , i cant pause , but other things work correctly

Comment: I know, just as I said, you use soundId to pause your sound, that's not correct!! Use the streamId to pause works fine.

Comment: uh... To make it more clear, I have updated my answer. I made my own demo with your code and it worked fine.....

Comment: thanks man , i tried this again and its worked . thank you so muh <3